# Paperclip image not showing, unpermitted params and routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, paperclip, strong-parameters

I'm trying to display images on the homepage with paperclip and I have unpermitted params and a routing error. I have tried various solutions including trying to pass in an array but I think this is happening because of my own lack of knowledge about rails.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Hdw1RzedMZdUE0cPrAXz0fkctQKfW9HX3S5ZwYh4lr0PwTJhHhVwcrglJv5qrMQF3T5YkcJZ9zBiRRRlCoNCNQ==", "document"=>{"doc"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feaf2db80f0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/1q/zfrk5kxj1015crsc13jwwrz40000gp/T/RackMultipart20170608-15326-1pcmtgl.jpg>, @original_filename="P1150645.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[doc][]\"; filename=\"P1150645.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}, "commit"=>"Upload Document"}
Unpermitted parameter: doc
   (1.9ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "documents" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2017-06-08 04:47:55 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-08 04:47:55 UTC]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-06-08 12:47:55 +0800
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Document Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" ORDER BY created_at
  Rendered documents/_documents.html.erb (56.7ms)
  Rendered documents/_new.html.erb (4.2ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" != 3)
  Conversation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE (conversations.sender_id = 3 OR conversations.recipient_id = 3)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."conversation_id" = ?  [["conversation_id", 4]]
  Rendered conversations/_index.html.erb (18.5ms)
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (141.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (5.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 426ms (Views: 401.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)


Started GET "/docs/original/missing.png" for ::1 at 2017-06-08 12:47:56 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/docs/original/missing.png"):
```

I've tried nesting the params given that document => doc is passing to an array, even if I leave the params blank it still uploads to the database with null fields and routing error, DocumentsController:

```
def doc_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:id, :doc)
end
```

I've tried multiple validations in here:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :doc
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :doc
end
```

I wondering if rendering the index is causing the routing error as I got rid of temporarily by re-routing but the image was still null, documents/_index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row around-xs">
        <center>
        <% @documents.each do |document| %>

          <li class="col-xs-3" id="item-grid">
            <%= link_to image_tag(document.doc.url, class: 'media-object', size:"108x152"), document.doc.url, target: '_blank' %>
            <% if @users %>
                <% if current_user.is_admin? %>
                            <%= link_to 'Remove', document_path(document), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %> 
                </li>

        <% end %>  
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

home.html.erb

```
<section id="about" class="about-section">
  <div class="container" id="services">

    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2" id="progpos"><h1>My Work</h1></div>

    <%= render 'documents/index' %>
    <br>
    <%= render 'documents/new' %>

  </div>
</section>
```

Please please help! thanks! documents/_new.html.erb

```
<% if @users %>
  <% if current_user.is_admin? %>

    <%= form_for @document, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <% if @document.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">

          <h2>
            <%= "#{pluralize(@document.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this document from being saved:" %>
          </h2>

          <ul>
            <% @document.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>

              <li>
                <%= msg %>
              </li>
            <% end %>

          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="form-group" style="width: 20%">
        <%= f.file_field :doc, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Document", multiple: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit 'Upload Document', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the whole of the controller and I've edited documents/_new.html.erb to how it looks:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @documents = Document.order('created_at')
    end

    def new
        @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      @document = Document.new(doc_params)
        if @document.save
            **params[:document][:doc].each do |d| #iterate over multiple attached files     
            @document.create(doc: d)**
        end
            flash[:success] = "The document was added!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render '_new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    if @document.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted photo!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error deleting photo!"
    end
  end

    private

    def doc_params
        params.require(:document).permit(:id, **document: {doc: []}**)
    end
end
```

I've added Pavans code to mine and i've also changed the params at the bottom which now gives me undefined method `create' for #. I think that's progress?

Comment: Could anyone else elaborate on what it might be? Because I feel I've exhausted all avenues aside from removing and reinstalling for a third time,

Answer (score 2):

> Unpermitted parameter: doc

You have `multiple :true` set for *field doc*, so *doc should an array* to accept the values. You should change the `doc_params` to below

```
def doc_params
  params.require(:document).permit(:id, doc: [])
end
```

> No handler found for
>   [#,
>   @original_filename="P1150645.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[doc][]\";
>   filename=\"P1150645.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]

You should also set `multipart: true` to the form to *handle file uploads*

```
<%= form_for @document, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/docs/original/missing.png")

Paperclip will try to find `missing.png` when an *object doesn't have an uploaded file* and you have tell Paperclip where to find it!

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :doc, :styles => { :medium => "250x250>", :thumb => "150x150>" }, :default_url => "/system/:attachment/:style/missing.jpg"
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :doc
end
```

***Update:***

Your `create` action should look like below

```
def create
  @document = Document.new(doc_params)
  if @document.save
    params[:document][:doc].each do |d| #iterate over multiple attached files     
      @doumnet.create(doc: d)
    end
    flash[:success] = "The document was added!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried that before and I get No handler found for [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feaf4b33cd8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/1q/zfrk5kxj1015crsc13jwwrz40000gp/T/RackMultipart20170608-15326-7rxufh.jpg>, @original_filename="P1150645.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[doc][]\"; filename=\"P1150645.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]

Comment: @Beamerr Updated!

Comment: @Beamerr Updated further!

Comment: I've also tried multipart: true on the form and I get the same No handler. I've tried pretty much every suggestion already on stack overflow. I can set the default url but thats not uploading the photos to the database?

Comment: @Beamerr Try adding `validates_attachment_content_type :doc, content_type: /\Aimage/` to the model

Comment: @Beamerr It should be `<%= form_for @document, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>` try with it again!

Comment: I've tried that already, I tried again, same error No Handler. Just for your knowledge If i remove doc: [], The page loads with blank thumbs and the original errors.

Comment: @Beamerr You should keep `doc: []`. Do you this exactly as it is `<%= form_for @document, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>`?

Comment: Can you paste your code? I want to see how did you put it.

Comment: Ok, I removed multiple: true from file_field but I still get unpermitted and routing error.

Comment: @Beamerr If you want to upload multiple attachements, then you should keept it. Updated my answer now. I hope this should resolve the problem!

Comment: Thanks, I did keep it in the form_for, I just removed it from the file_field as it was repeated and causing a conflict. I now have this undefined method `each' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fee1d91f948>. Is it because this is a nested array?...."document"=>{"doc"=>#<ActionDispatch

Comment: @Beamerr Brother! You should keep `multiple :true in `file_field` and  remove it from the `form_for`!

Comment: I've done that now and it's back to no handler error.

Comment: @Beamerr I believe the `new` method should be `@document = Document.new` Try this with all my changes.

Comment: No dice i'm afraid still the same with all your changes.